# How to get the rectangle of the text in an element of the web page (not the rectangle of the element itself)?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes the rectangle of the text in an element is different from the rectangle of the element itself. I want to get the rectangle of the text, not the one of element.

I tried two MDN functions: `Element.getClientRects()` and `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`, but they don't find the rectangle of the text.

For example, there is following button:

```
<button style="position:absolute; left:58px; top:224px; width:100px; height:40px;">

  Both the span and the paragraph have a border set.

</button><br/>
```

Both getClientRects and getBoundingClientRect only find the rectangle of button itself.

How can I find the rectangle of the text "Both the span and the paragraph have a border set."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/) can give it to you, thanks to its [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/getBoundingClientRect) method:

```js
const range = document.createRange();
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const textNode = button.firstChild;
range.selectNode( textNode );
// get the bounding box of the TextNode
const rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();

const border = document.getElementById('border');
border.style.top = rect.top + 'px';
border.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
border.style.width = rect.width + 'px';
border.style.height = rect.height + 'px';
```

```css
#border {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button style="position:absolute; left:58px; top:24px; width:100px; height:40px;">

  Both the span and the paragraph have a border set.

</button><br/>

<div id="border"></div>
```

Comment: Kaiido, thanks a lot! It works well and is just what I want.